# Kann „auch“ als „doch“ benutzt werden?

Tags: adverb

Teilweise verstehe ich die von *auch* im nächsten Gespräch gespielte Rolle:

> – Boah! Guck mal Martins neue Auto. Er soll ein Schweinegeld haben!
>   – Jo, ist auch so.

Aber als ich ausschließlich nach einem Regenschutz gefragt habe, hat eine Verkäuferin (in Köln, falls das eine Rolle spielt) *auch* wie im nächsten Gespräch benutzt:

> – (…) oder haben Sie keinen mehr?
>   – Ne, wir haben den **auch** (wärend Sie mir den Regenschutz sucht, den sie nie fand)

Da hätte ich *doch* anstelle von *auch* erwartet. Ist es richtig, was sie sagte?

Comment: Ich glaube, du hast "doch" noch nicht verstanden. In beiden Beispielen ist die "Aufgabe" des Wortes ein reines "affirming". "Doch" kontert ein negativ, oder bettelt um Zustimmung aber es passt in beiden Beispielen nicht. Zumindest nicht so wie ich sie verstehe.

Comment: Übrigends: ich denke nicht, dass der Dialekt (Du hast Köln erwähnt) hier eine Rolle spielt.

Comment: Siehe auch die Beispiele für [auch (Adverb)](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auch_Adverb) und [doch (Partikel)](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/doch_Partikel) im Duden.

Comment: In the first example, neither sentence is particularly idiomatic. You'd say "Martins neues Auto" or, more colloquially, "das neue Auto von Martin". I don't understand what the answer is supposed to tell me; I'd get "Jo, so ist es." (yes, he has money) or "Jo, ist es." (yes, his car).

Comment: @ c.P. : Das hat jetzt nichts mit dieser konkreten Frage zu tun, aber ich weiß nicht wie ich dich sonst kontaktieren soll. In http://german.stackexchange.com/users/1691/c-p steht dass du kein Muttersprachler bist ("I'm not a native speaker"), aber das glaube ich dir nicht. Jeder Mensch hat irgend eine Muttersprache. Ich vermute du meinst "I'm not an english native speaker". Schreibe stattdessen bitte lieber was tatsächlich deine Muttersprache ist. Vielleicht so: http://german.stackexchange.com/users/1487/hubert-schölnast

Comment: Ok, stimmt was du sagst, HS. Ich dachte es wäre deutlich, weil die Seite ums Deutsch geht. Aber ich habe "des Deutschen" hinzugefügt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aus deiner Beschreibung schließe ich, dass Du in einem Geschäft einen Regenschutz kaufen wolltest und entweder nach einem bestimmten Regenschutz gefragt hast oder Du hast, da die Verkäuferin lange gesucht hat, angenommen, dass das Geschäft keinen einzigen Regenschutz mehr hat.

In dem Fall ist `auch` schon angebracht.

Die Verkäuferin wollte damit sagen, dass sie das Kleidungsstück (`auch`) (neben vielen Anderen) haben.

Das Wort `doch` wäre angebracht gewesen, wenn Du ihr (enttäuscht) unterstellt hättest

```
A) Sie haben keine mehr! :(

B) Doch, wir haben den noch!
```

*Mit sich selbst redend könnte sie auch sagen (obwohl sie sich vielleicht nicht ganz sicher ist):*

```
Wir haben die [Regencapes] doch! (In Gedanken: "oder doch nicht?")
```

---

From your description I assume that you were asking for a rain cape. You either asked for a certain rain cape or you assumed, while the saleswoman was searching, that the shop the rain capes were out of stock.

In this case `auch` is correct.

The saleswomen expressed that they have that item of clothing in stock (among others, `also`).

The word `doch` would be correct if you have had (in a disappointed way) implied that they're out of stock:

```
A) Sie haben keine mehr! :(

B) Doch, wir haben die [Regencapes] noch.
```

*Talking to herself she could also say (maybe unsure):*

```
Wir haben die [Regencapes] doch! (In Gedanken: "oder doch nicht?")
```

Answer (score 2):

"Auch" addiert Sachen. Das tut es auch in den Beispielen.
Im ersten Beispiel, "auch" ist gut und kann nicht ersetzt werden. Es kombiniert zwei Verben.

> Er SOLL Geld haben und HAT es auch.

In Englisch würde man das mit "and" machen.

> "He is said to be very rich."
>   "And he is."
>   (keine sehr gute Übersetzung)

Im zweiten Beispiel könnte das "auch" das Kleidungsstück zu anderen Kleidungsstücken "addieren", die sie dort haben. 
Wenn es wirklich eine Partikel der Affirmation sein sollte (was für mich komisch klingt), dann wäre es "schon" und nicht "doch".

It is also possible, if remotely, that she actually said "noch" and not "auch".

Answer (score 1):

Im Amerikanischen kann 'too' zur betonten Bejahung einer verneinten Aussage verwendet werden:

> I'm not going to brush my teeth!
>   -You are too!

In diesem Fall kann man 'too' mit 'doch' übersetzen. Dabei ist darauf zu achten, dass sich vor 'too' kein Beistrich und danach ein Ausrufezeichen befindet (sonst entspräche es ja dem englischen 'also').

Mir ist kein (deutscher) Dialekt bekannt, in dem 'auch' auf diese Weise verwendet wird.
Im Hochdeutschen ist dies nicht möglich.